# Using Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

Using Rdlc.

Always getting First Record repeatedly, i used

```
=First(Fields!emp_address.Value, "emp_management_systemDataSet_employee")
```

When I removing First then showing error.

Comment: I did not understnd you question but I am sure removing `First` will def give error. :)

Comment: that is i am asking buddy if I remove first then it will show error for sure, so what should i write their to retrieve records correctly, earlier i used =Fields!emp_address.value,"emp_management_employee") but it is showing error!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have dragged a Table into your rdlc interface, and assigned a datasource to the table, all you need should be 
    =Fields!emp_address.Value

Comment: This worked, just a simple thing dragged me to hell.  Thanks A TON :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. It's always the little things that cause the most hassle

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
=IIf(Fields!emp_address.Value, "emp_management_systemDataSet_employee")
```